# Remove every char in a object column to get the date time

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe extracted from a website using API, However the date time column contains some string like below. The data type is currently an object and while converting it to date time I am getting error.

```
   date                 Language  session
2022-12-14-03:15:26     English  Morning
2022-12-15-13:13:30     French   Afternoon
file_2022-12-14-05:10:16 Spanish  Morning
test_2022-12-14-10:08:26 Chinese  Morning

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Is there anyway I can convert this data frame like below

```
   date                 Language  session
2022-12-14-03:15:26     English  Morning
2022-12-15-13:13:30     French   Afternoon
2022-12-14-05:10:16    Spanish  Morning
2022-12-14-10:08:26    Chinese  Morning
```

Comment: You could take the last 19 characters. `data[-19:]`

Answer (score 0):

There's definitely a more elegant solution, but depending on your needs, you could just take a slice of the date columns using negative indexes and convert that to a date object.
i.e. `data[-19:]`

Comment: There is a missing `:` in your slicing